# Was the name of the car wash A1 or A1A?

Tags: breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad*, why did Skyler and Walt say: "Have an A1 day"? Shouldn't they say: "Have an A1A day"?

The car wash signs clearly reads: A1A, not A1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just a rhyme (A1A->A1-Day). It's the car wash's motto and it's supposed to be catchy. It's for the same reason you'd hear slogans like *Do the Dew* and not *Do the **Mountain** Dew* etc. They're far less catchy, and it's supposed to stick in your mind and be friendly.

Comment: Good answer, but [Domino's](http://www.dominos.com/) no longer has a "Pizza" in its name.

Comment: Shows you how up to date I am... ;) Edited.